# Wordpress query posts with multiple post_meta data

Tags: wp-query, query, post-meta, wpdb

I want to display posts in a slider that are marked as "featured".
For this i created a post meta box with a checkbox.
Now i have the following query

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts, wp_postmeta WHERE wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'theme_featured_post' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '1' AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_posts.post_date < NOW() ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

But i need another value from the post_meta table as well. So how can I select the second meta_key in the query. 
I could query it with

> get_post_meta( $postid, 'custom_image')

Cause transactions are expensive, i would like to include it in one query.
The custom_image is an image id and has its own row in the table.

Comment: You simply need to use the meta_query arg in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a normal practice to use raw SQL in WP, unless you absolutely *have* to. You should be using normal WP APIs for this and optimizing *after* you encounter a performance issue.

Among other things APIs will transparently *cache* data (such as post meta) within page load and between page loads with Object Cache installed. In typical cases Object Cache will be *faster* than database fetch (which is the point of it).

Comment: Use the `meta_query` argument as per [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).